# How to fix Jupyter R kernel broken by pillar package version (1.3)?

Tags: r, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I am trying to run the following library loading commands in a Jupyter R Kernel.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(MESS)
library(MLmetrics)
library(ggpubr)
library(ggpmisc)
```

When I run that block, logs print the following messages:

```
[I 07:55:13.618 LabApp] Build is up to date
[I 07:55:14.385 LabApp] Kernel started: 80106139-3ada-4d73-9d46-47b3e173953c
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) :
  namespace 'pillar' 1.3.1 is being loaded, but >= 1.4.0 is required
Calls: :: ... namespaceImportFrom -> asNamespace -> loadNamespace

[I 07:55:17.374 LabApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), new random ports
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) :
  namespace 'pillar' 1.3.1 is being loaded, but >= 1.4.0 is required
Calls: :: ... namespaceImportFrom -> asNamespace -> loadNamespace

[I 07:55:20.368 LabApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (2/5), new random ports
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) :
  namespace 'pillar' 1.3.1 is being loaded, but >= 1.4.0 is required
Calls: :: ... namespaceImportFrom -> asNamespace -> loadNamespace

[I 07:55:23.368 LabApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (3/5), new random ports
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) :
  namespace 'pillar' 1.3.1 is being loaded, but >= 1.4.0 is required
Calls: :: ... namespaceImportFrom -> asNamespace -> loadNamespace

[I 07:55:26.365 LabApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (4/5), new random ports
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) :
  namespace 'pillar' 1.3.1 is being loaded, but >= 1.4.0 is required
Calls: :: ... namespaceImportFrom -> asNamespace -> loadNamespace

[W 07:55:29.374 LabApp] KernelRestarter: restart failed
[W 07:55:29.374 LabApp] Kernel 80106139-3ada-4d73-9d46-47b3e173953c died, removing from map
```

I am using Windows 10 with Anaconda3. I tried to reinstall/upgrade pillar using the command `conda install -c conda-forge r-pillar`, but no success. I also tried to use `install.packages` and `update.packages` in R environment, but no success.

Can anyone help me to solve that issues?